# What might be the best way to load list of HTML content on android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, webview, android-webview

I am trying to load list of Strings with html tags(HTML contents) on my application using **recyclerView**. So far I have tried using **Html.fromHtml()** method on recyclerView viewholder but could not find any luck since, it only support limited HTML tags.

**Html.fromHtml supports:**

- p
- ul
- li
- div
- span
- strong
- b
- em
- cite
- dfn
- i
- big
- small
- font
- blockquote
- tt
- a
- u
- del
- s
- strike
- sup
- sub
- h1
- h2
- h3
- h4
- h5
- h6
- img
- br

what I need to parse are those tags which is not supported by Html.fromHtml such as bullet points, inline CSS

So I decided to load content on **WebView**. I know it is not a good practice to implement WebView as recyclerView item but I could not find any alternative solution over this.

Is there any mechanism from where I could get reliable solution. As webview inside recyclerview has many issues such as scrolling issue, asynchronous content loading and soon.
Please help me how can I get smooth scrolling on this matter.

So far I have done this

```
class MessageViewHolder internal constructor(itemView: View) :  RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) ,ViewHolderBinder{
private var webView: WebView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ac_web_view)

override fun bind(position: Int) {
    super.bind(position)
    loadContentOnWebView(message) // html content
}

private fun loadContentOnWebView( message: String) {
    webView?.apply { 
        isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = false
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
        webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                view.context.startActivity(
                    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                )
                return true
            }
        }
        loadDataWithBaseURL(null, message.changeHtmlLinkColor(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you use [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) HTML parser to get html tags with target url?

Comment: Jsoup? OR Try some kind of scraping or expose an API to get the data from your website if that is what you require

Comment: I am not loading content through URL

Answer (score 0):

If you have to set only string you only need to use Html.fromHtml() in your ViewHolder class (no need to add a webview for only text), add this code in your ViewHolder class, maybe it works!

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    view.text = Html.fromHtml("your HTML String", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
} else {
    view.text = Html.fromHtml("your HTML String")
}
```

Comment: He already mentioned in the code that some tags are not supported this way

Comment: he also needs to mention that tag in the code, also check that he use Html.toHtml() instead of Html.fromHtml(), maybe you must have to read code very carefully! @gtxtreme